# Read lines and match against pattern

Tags: bash, read

I can't figure this out. I need to look at every line in a file and check whether it matches a word that is given in a variable.

I started with command `read`, but I don't know what I am supposed to use after that. I tried `grep`, but I probably used it wrongly.

```
while read line; do 
  if [ $condition  ] ;then echo "ok" fi
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a quickie for you, simply what we're doing is

Line 1: While reading file into variable `line`

Line 2: Match a regex, echo the `$line` if matching the word "bird" echo that line. Do whatever actions you need here, in this if statement.

Line 3: End of while loop, which pipes in the file `foo.text`

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
  if [[ $line =~ bird ]] ; then echo $line; fi
done <foo.text
```

Note that "bird" is a regex. So that you could replace it with for example: `bird.*word` to match the same line with a regular expression.

Try it with a file like so, called `foo.text` with the contents:

```
my dog is brown
her cat is white
the bird is the word
```

Comment: What exactly means ^$  ? I undetstand that it is some kind of regex, but when I replace it with my own word and own txt file it doesn't work

Comment: `^anything$` means "match the beginning and end of line", ^ is beginning, and $ means end. so that the whole line is "anything". If you want a partial match like you have a line that says "my dog is brown" and you just want to match dog, get rid of the ^ and $, and just have "dog" there. (edited code to reflect a simplification in regex)

Comment: If you don't intend to do any processing for each line, you should just use `grep` and skip using `read` entirely.

Answer (score 6):

The easier way to do this, is using `grep` (or `egrep`).

```
grep bird file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script that passes in two arguments (filename and variable)... There's also a hardcoded version beneath that.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ $# -lt 2 ] && echo "wrong number of args" && exit 1
file=$1
var=$2
while read line; do
    if  echo "$line" | grep -q "$var"; then echo "ok"; fi
done < "$file"
exit 0

[user@myserver ~]$ myscript file.txt some_text
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to hardcode the file (and variable) 
 rather than passing in as an arguments...

```
while read line; do
    if  echo "$line" | grep -q "some_text"; then echo "ok"; fi
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what processing you want to do for each line, `sed` is another option. I'd only recommend it if you already intend to use `sed` on each line, though.

```
sed -n '/regex/p' foo.text
```

I'm using sed's `-n` option to suppress normal output. And I'm using the `p` command to print only the matching lines.

You could combine this with editing commands, too (the processing I was referring to).

```
sed -n '/regex/{s/pattern/replacement/;p}' foo.text
```

If you don't want to do any processing on each line, then I agree with [steviethecat's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190828/83381) that `grep` is the best solution, being the cleanest and fastest.

```
grep regex foo.text
```

If you want to do processing that requires additional Unix commands, then (and only then) do I recommend using `read`.

Comment: Downvote with no comment!? This is a legitimate technique. The fact that the OP is trying to use `read` instead of just `grep` and that the accepted answer does not use `grep` implies that they want to do some kind of processing on each line.