# while reading lines from a file, need to print the previous line if matches found to given string using bash script

Tags: bash, files, grep, read

I have a file say `file.txt` and contents looks like below with more than 10000 lines.

```
Wed May 27 15:41:29 PDT 2020  
Entering directory : /aaa/bbb/ccc  
Wed May 27 15:42:30 PDT 2020  
Entering directory : /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd  
Wed May 27 15:43:19 PDT 2020  
Entering directory : /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee  
Wed May 27 15:44:25 PDT 2020  
Leaving directory : /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee  
Wed May 27 15:45:37 PDT 2020  
Leaving directory : /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd'  
Wed May 27 15:46:42 PDT 2020  
Leaving directory : /aaa/bbb/ccc
```

### *What need to done*

Need to print out which directory taking how much time based on the timestamp before Entering and Leaving directory.

### *Output should be*

```
_Directory_ : `/aaa/bbb/ccc`  
_Time taken_ : `00:05:13`
```

Entering time for this directory is : `Wed May 27 15:41:29 PDT 2020` and Leaving time is : `Wed May 27 15:46:42 PDT 2020` So the time difference is the output.
similarly need to print both directory path and the time difference for other instance as well.

Tried searching in the forum and got [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190815), but it didn't solve my problem fully. Though I am not a pro in shell script. So if someone could help to me get the output will be really great.

Thank You

Comment: Is the tick at the end of `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd'` supposed to be there or is it a typo? Either explain it or fix it. Are there really blank chars at the end of each line in your input? If so how do we know when a directory name ends since a directory name could have blanks at the end? Again - explain or fix.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but based on the [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiline-techniques.html) documentation if you do

```
cat file.txt | sed -n 'N;l;D' | sed -n '/.*\/aaa\/bbb\/ccc\s*\$/p'
```

you will get

```
Wed May 27 15:41:29 PDT 2020  \nEntering directory : /aaa/bbb/ccc  $
Wed May 27 15:46:42 PDT 2020  \nLeaving directory : /aaa/bbb/ccc$
```

which could simplify the problem, provided you know the full paths of all the directories in question, which you would have to loop over.

Not sure about the date arithmetic to get the elapsed time, but if you can extract the dates from the above, converting to unix time (seconds since Jan 1, 1970) might be a start. For example

```
date -d "Wed May 27 15:41:29 PDT 2020" +%s
```

gives

```
1590619289
```

So if in your script you can get the dates into variables (which I will do verbatim)

```
ENTERDATE="Wed May 27 15:41:29 PDT 2020"
LEAVEDATE="Wed May 27 15:46:42 PDT 2020"
```

and convert them into unixtime

```
ENTERSECONDS=`date -d "$ENTERDATE" +%s`
LEAVESECONDS=`date -d "$LEAVEDATE" +%s`
```

you can get the duration in seconds as follows

```
DURATION=$(($LEAVESECONDS - $ENTERSECONDS))
```

which in this case is

```
313
```

There may be some packages available the would better support date arithmetic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You @orylis. I need to combine all of those and tweak a bit to get the exact  output. I am preparing the script and hope that will help me to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do what you want using GNU awk for `mktime()` and making some assumptions about your input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }
sub(/^Entering directory : /,"") {
    enterSecs[$0] = epochSecs
    next
}
sub(/^Leaving directory : /,"") {
    deltaSecs = epochSecs - enterSecs[$0]
    delete enterSecs[$0]

    hrs  = int(deltaSecs / (60*60))
    mins = int((deltaSecs % (60*60)) / 60)
    secs = deltaSecs % 60

    printf "_Directory_ : `%s`\n", $0
    printf "_Time taken_ : `%02d:%02d:%02d`\n", hrs, mins, secs
    next
}
{
    gsub(/:/," ")
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprmayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", $2)+2) / 3
    epochSecs = mktime( sprintf("%04d %02d %02d %02d %02d %02d", $NF, mthNr, $3, $4, $5, $6) )
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
_Directory_ : `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee`
_Time taken_ : `00:01:06`
_Directory_ : `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd`
_Time taken_ : `00:03:07`
_Directory_ : `/aaa/bbb/ccc`
_Time taken_ : `00:05:13`
```